# How to get my regular expression to extract information, not just check

Tags: php, regex, street-address, zipcode, postal-code

I have a regular expression for checking whether a string is zip/postal code or not. But I would really like to also to be able to extract that from a full address (or, if possible, any string).

Here is my current regular expression:

```
/^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s\d[a-zA-Z]\d)|([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d))$/
```

If necessary I'm willing to settle for a function (I'm checking with PHP) but I'd rather the regexp do the work if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match`, which I assume you're already using when you're checking a string against your regular expression, also gives you back the actual text that matched your pattern.

```
preg_match($regex, $input, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

The third argument is filled with the results of trying to match the regex against your input. `$matches[0]` will contain text that matched the whole pattern, while higher indexes will contain text that matched against capturing subpatterns (the parts of the pattern enclosed in parentheses).

However, in your case, you've enclosed your pattern with the start-of-input `^` and  end-of-input `$` characters, which means that any matches must include the *entire* input string (or an entire line in multiline mode).  You'd have to get rid of the `^` and `$` before trying to use this pattern to extract a postal code from a larger string.

Comment: Perfect! You're right, I was using preg_match() and grouped the variables into an array thanks to the third parameter. But the info about the `^` and `$` is what I needed

Answer (score 2):

PHP will extract the groupings in `()` into an array with [`preg_match()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php):

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = "/^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s\d[a-zA-Z]\d)|([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d))$/";
preg_match($pattern, $your_source, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Yep, I knew that. But, it doesn't help me extract that regexp from a larger string; only variables from within the regexp

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with a full address, why not rely on a service that can accurately extract and verify an address and parse it's components (including the full ZIP Code), providing a nice response?  It would certainly eliminate any guessing. The screenshot below shows a tool by SmartyStreets that can extract addresses from all sorts of text.  In the interest of full disclosure, I'm a software developer at [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com).

https://smartystreets.com/account/extract

[image: LiveAddress extraction]